# Any task manager to sort processes by disk or network activity?

Tags: system-monitor

The Task Manager in Windows 8+ has Disk and Network activity columns for processes. Processes can be sorted by those with highest activity on Disk or on Network.

I do not find these options in the System Monitor in Ubuntu. Is there any GUI or console task manager that has these features?

Answer (score 0):

Executing the command `apt-cache search monitor | grep -i system` will give you a list of packages related to system monitoring. You can Search for information about a package at http://packages.ubuntu.com/